# NameError: Name 'ShiftArr' is not defined

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
# indices to calculate pair-wise products (H, V, D1, D2)
shifts = [[0,1], [1,0], [1,1], [-1,1]]
# calculate pairwise components in each orientation
for itr_shift in range(1, len(shifts) + 1):
    OrigArr = structdis
    reqshift = shifts[itr_shift-1] # shifting index
    for i in range(structdis.shape[0]):
        for j in range(structdis.shape[1]):
            if(i + reqshift[0] >= 0 and i + reqshift[0] < structdis.shape[0] \
               and j + reqshift[1] >= 0 and j  + reqshift[1] < structdis.shape[1]):
                ShiftArr[i, j] = OrigArr[i + reqshift[0], j + reqshift[1]]
            else:
                ShiftArr[i, j] = 0
```

If I try to run the code, I get the following error:

> NameError: Name 'ShiftArr' is not defined

How can I solve this error?

Comment: What _is_ `ShiftArr`? Where does it come from?

Comment: Post the _entire_ code. That should help...

Comment: The error message is fairly self explanatory. You are trying to make an assignment to `ShiftArr` but python does not know of an variable/object with that name in the scope visible to it at that point. So if you are in a function it is not in the scope of that function or in the global scope outside that function. If you have defined it somewhere, then it has been defined in a scope that is not visible from where you are trying to use it.

Comment: I added entire code, could you see what's wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things you have not defined ShiftArr before you have used it. This is what the error is saying.

It looks like you first use ShiftArr in your nested loop, but nowhere before have you said something like ShiftArr = ...

If you add ShiftArr = [] before your first for loop, this should solve your issue I think. It's a little difficult to understand what you're trying to do as your variable names aren't super informative - this might help you when drying to fix errors in your code.